# Close modal dialog from external thread - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am struggling to find a way to create the Forms functionality that I want using C#.

Basically, I want to have a modal dialog box that has a specified timeout period.  It seems like this should be easy to do, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Once I call `this.ShowDialog(parent)`, the program flow stops, and I have no way of closing the dialog without the user first clicking a button.

I tried creating a new thread using the BackgroundWorker class, but I can't get it to close the dialog on a different thread.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx). Set its [Interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval.aspx) property to be your timeout and its [Tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) event handler to close the dialog.

```
partial class TimedModalForm : Form
{
    private Timer timer;

    public TimedModalForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3000;
        timer.Tick += CloseForm;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void CloseForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

The timer runs on the UI thread so it is safe to close the form from the tick event handler.

Answer (score 12):

You will need to call the Close method on the thread that created the form:

```
theDialogForm.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(Close));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really just want a modal dialog then I found this to be the best solution by far: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/CsMsgBoxTimeOut.aspx (read the comments section for a small modification).

If you want to display your own form modally, then the solution from adrianbanks is best.

Answer (score 1):

you can [Invoke](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx) the close from your background thread